# Recoding a for loop summation in R

Tags: r

I am creating a vector, vsum, with length equal to the length of a column in a dataframe, df.  The values in each element of vsum are equal to the summation of rows from specific columns in df multiplied by an element in a vector, wts.  I am currently using for loops to achieve the result.  Is there a better way to do this with vectorized code or some other base R function?

```
vsum  <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 1000)
wts <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 4)
df <- data.frame(v1=numeric(),v2=numeric(), ... , v50=numeric())

# Values added to wts and df.  1000 rows in df.

cols <- c(3,14,25,36)

for (j in 1:4){
  vsum <- vsum + wts[j]*df[,cols[j]]
}
```

Comment: What you describe there is simple matrix multiplication. Turn the data.frame into a matrix and then use %*%.

Comment: Many thanks, Roland.  I was able to replicate my expected results with the %*%.   Thank you for helping out an R newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
rowSums( df[ , cols] * matrix(wts, nrow=nrow(df), byrow=TRUE) )
```

- Exctract the `col` columns from `df` and treat them like a matrix A
- Create a matrix B of the same dimensions as A, but fill it with `wts` by row
- Then take the rowsums of A*B

---

Option 2:

```
df[ , col[1]]*wts[1] + ... + df[ , col[4]]*wts[4]
```

- Just multiply the first column in `col` times the first value in `wts`
- Repeat for all columns and add them up

Comment: Thanks, Dan Y.  I was able to replicate my for loops with the following... rowSums( df[ ,cols]*matrix(wts, nrow=nrow(df), ncol = length(wts), byrow = TRUE))

Comment: I don't have enough reputation right now for my up vote to count.   I really appreciate you helping out an R newbie.  :)